# Find an equation in $x$ and $k$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, roots

Find an equation in $x$ and $k$ if, $$6u-8v+2=k^2$$ $$u^{2}=1+2v^{2}$$ $$v=2xy$$ $$u=x^2+2xy-y^2$$  Since we have 4 equations, we can eliminate 3 variables. But somehow, I'm not able to find an equation in $x$ and $k$. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "Since we have 4 equations, we can eliminate 3 variables" Not so sure this is always the case for non-linear systems. You might always end up with an implicit equation involving several variables. I could be wrong in general though and could well be wrong in this particular case!

Comment: First of all we have:
$$6(x^2+2xy-y^2)-16xy+2=k^2$$ but also :
$$(16xy-2+k^2)^2=36(1+8 (xy)^2) $$ 
or:
$$(8xy-4(k^2-2))^2=18((k^2-2)^2-4) $$
if you solve this equation you can find the value of $xy$ ,hence you can eliminate $y$ in the first equation :
$$6(x^2+2(xy)-\left(\frac{xy}{x}\right)^2)-16(xy)+2=k^2$$

Comment: @Elaqqad Thanks!